# Opening a terminal from Linux Makefile

Tags: c++, c, linux, makefile

Can we open a new terminal tab or window from the existing terminal using a makefile or some c file.

If yes how? Thanks in advance for replying.

P.S. I want to do this because first in the terminal I want to run the server file then I want to open the new terminal and there run the file for the client.

From the second terminal I want to continue running the script.

Comment: GNU Screen? (( http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/ ) and ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen ))

Comment: Why do you want to?  And remind me not to use your makefile...please!

Comment: I'm going to agree on using screen... or tmux... or possibly running the server with &

Comment: @jonatthon.. I want to server and client from the same terminal. And don't want the user to worry about this. So want the makefile to do this changes....

Comment: @abhishek: OK - for your case it has uses.  It would not be a good idea to distribute the makefile for use in automated builds, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try running `xterm` (the most available terminal window program) with the program to run as the shell argument.

```
xterm ./my_client &
```

For this to work the DISPLAY environmental variable would have to be set to something usable (which it probably will be if you are running X windows locally -- if you are connecting remotely then it's more complicated).

If you want to get fancy you can try to determine what other terminal window programs are available and what the user would want to use, but I know some of them have a different way of specifying which "shell" to run.

Comment: This gives me an error ---->>>>> xterm Xt error: Can't open display: 
xterm:  DISPLAY is not set

Comment: I said DISPLAY had to be set.  If you aren't using X windows you should use the screen method mention by someone else, but since you said open another window I assumed that you were using one of the many terminal emulator programs (xterm, gnome-terminal, konsole, ...) and launching another X program from within one of them usually works as DISPLAY is usually (correctly) set.

Comment: Actually, This worked on my computer. But we are supposed to get this running in our Labs computers where we cannot install anything at our will. The piece of code is giving error there.

Comment: @abhishekgupta92: Well you are going to have to provide more information about your lab set up.  Try running `DISPLAY=:0.0 xterm ./my_client &` .  If that doesn't work then you are probably using a remote connection (or X isn't involved).  If you are using ssh to connect to the lab computer then use `ssh -X lab_computer_name` to connect (that's in upper case X and will turn on X forwarding), and then do `xterm ./my_client &` (without the DISPLAY= )