# output to a new terminal

Tags: c, redirect

Suppose I create a thread from my "main" thread, which aims to monitor and print some variables in "main". But "main" is also generating some output, so I want to print the outputs of these two threads separately. How can I redirect the output of the new thread to a new console other than the one "main" thread is using in my c program?

Comment: What operating system is this running on?

Comment: Nitpick: fedora isn't an operating system. It's a distribution.

Answer (score 2):

I would output the monitoring information to a file, then use `tail -f filename` to display it in my other terminal.

That has the advantage that you can run `grep` or what-have-you on the output as well.

Comment: I may have to type something like "tail -f" from time to time. Is there a way to dynamically monitor the content of a file via console? That is, if something is appended to the file, the console would automatically scroll down and display the newly added just like "printf()" to it?

Comment: @sino You just described what `tail -f` does.

Answer (score 2):

I would go with writing the data to a log file and then using `tail -f log_file.txt` from another window to watch it since that way you get to keep a copy of the data, but if you decide that you need to use separate terminals then you can just open the new terminal (tty) like a regular file.  The main problem with this is that you probably really want it to open a new terminal window for you as well.

Opening a new terminal window to do something like this is tricky and is different between different terminal emulators. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3738752/opening-a-terminal-from-linux-makefile) is another question about opening new terminals from a make file.  You could try doing the same thing from your program or from a script that runs your program and run `cat` or `tail` in the new terminal to be your log window.

```
#!/bin/sh
truncate  --size=0 ./logfile.txt
xterm "tail -f ./logfile.txt" 2>&1 > /dev/null &
your_program --log-file=./logfile.txt
```

I don't currently know of a better way to accomplish this.

Another thing you might want to look into is `syslog`.

Answer (score 0):

What would you expect to happen in such case (externally)?

If you run a program you are attached to a console. You of course don't have to write output to the console (you can use files), but the console cannot be duplicated obviously.

Isn't using a different file descriptor good enough for you?

Comment: Basically I have two threads, one acting as server and the other client. And I want to monitor the status of both via consoles in real-time. If I print both outputs on the same console, they are interleaved and thus not very readable. So I'm wondering if there is a way to output to two different consoles, one for server and the other for client, in my c program?

Comment: @sino I guess I should have been more clear. No you can't. Again what the heck would that do on the system? What if the console is opened through SSH, or if it is an old-school physical monitor. To reiterate, why don't you just write to a different file descriptor?

Comment: Because I want to display both output in REAL-TIME. If I write to a file, I may have to type something like "tail -f" from time to time to be updated.

Comment: @sino Well, in that case I should note that most terminal emulators employ heavy caching during drawing operations and therefore the output will never be real-time.